# a newbi question on php array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [inline_comment] => inline_comment [page] => page [comment] => Comment )
```

I want to array turn to be :~

```
Array ( [0] => inline_comment [1] => page [2] => Comment )
```

how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$new = array();
foreach ($old as $entry) $new[] = $entry;
?>
```

or better

```
<?php
$new = array_values($old);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
    'inline_comment' => 'inline_comment',
    'page' => 'page',
    'comment' => 'Comment'
);
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear whether you want to get the keys or values from the array.

If you want to get the keys, then you probably want to look up the [`array_keys()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$new_array = array_keys($old_array);
```

I believe this will do exactly what you want.

If you want to get the values, then [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will do what you want. It works in pretty much the same way as `array_keys()` above.

Comment: Nope, `array_keys` will return what it says, the keys of the array. The OP wants the values.

Comment: @Shef - heh, I'd already edited the question by the time you posted your comment  :)